# Count Number of dates in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Probably a naive question, but new to it.

I have a dataset having multiple date entries. I want to create a new dataframe such that it has 2 columns, date and count.

My dataset looks like this :

```
Date
01/01/2020
01/10/2019
01/11/2019
01/12/2019
02/01/2020
02/10/2019
02/11/2019
02/12/2019
03/01/2020
03/10/2019
03/11/2019
03/12/2019
04/01/2020
04/10/2019
04/11/2019
04/12/2019
05/01/2020
05/10/2019
05/11/2019
05/12/2019
06/01/2020
```

I have tried :

```
import pandas as pd
count = df.groupby(['Date']).count()
```

But it is just returning me the dates grouped by and not the count.

the expected output is :

```
Date        Count
```

Since the dates are repeated in the dataset, each date should represent the same count. i.e. if 01/01/2020 has 5 entries then it should have count as 5 in all 5 entries.

Can anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: look at transform : `df['Count']=df.groupby('Date').transform('count')`

Comment: `.groupby('Date').size()` will return series with count

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks for your response, however I am getting this `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-46-37a15246bc7f>", line 1, in <module>
    df1['Count']=df1.groupby('date').transform('count')

 
KeyError: date'`

Comment: It's a key error, you are using `date` as column but I think it should be `Date` caps `D`

Comment: @N.Moudgil I tried .size() but it creates the count column with NaN values. Not sure why. Can you please help. @anky_91 .transform('Count') is not working saying `TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: @vp7 yeah, my bad, use the column name before transform: `df.groupby('Date')['Date'].transform('count')`